# Is there a solution to speed up the "Galois field" gf function in Matlab

Tags: finite-fields, galois-extensions, galois-representations

Is there a solution to speed up the "Galois field"  gf function in Matlab,  where most of the execution time is wasted inside this function. What are the proposals to increase its speed?

Comment: This is not on-topic.  Support for commercial software, such as Matlab, can be requested from the vendor.  Claims like "most of the execution time is wasted inside this function" cannot be verified here, much less mitigated.

Comment: I mean, is there a code or algorithm for calculating Galois fields that I use instead of the gf function?

Comment: Perhaps you should state what you want such an algorithm to do in more detail than just "calculating Galois fields".  You might be trying to construct a finite field, or something quite different.  What is the input, and what is the desired output?

Comment: This algorithm is used in ٌRandom Linear Network Coding Encoding and Decoding    x=size(Y_TX{1,1},1)
                         g_loc=gf(randi(2^q-1,[f,x]),q);